# Question on interpreting odd numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a question concerning the algebraic interpretation of odd and even numbers. Throughout this text, the use of $n$ will be interpreted such that $n \in Z$. It seems apparent to me that the expression $2n + 1$ refers to the set of odd numbers, and $2n$ is the set of even numbers. While this is quite elementary, expressions of more modified sets have striked me of much interest. How am I to interpret the set $4n + 1$, for example? After writing out the extension of this set, which is $\{..., -7, -3, 1, 5, 9, ...\}$, it seems to me that this set contains half of all the odd numbers. And the expression $4n \pm 1$, again, refers to the set of *all* odd numbers. Is there a quick way to identify such expressions and replace them with their simpler forms without writing out their extensions every time? For example, if I had known that $4n \pm 1$ is the same thing as $2n + 1$, I could have utilized this knowledge and replaced the former expression with the latter in any given mathematical problem. Given the expression $9n \pm 3$, how am I supposed to simplify this into a more concise expression?

A question similar to this that I have is how I can merge two algebraic expressions with one another? Some simple examples are the expressions $k + 2$ and $k - 2$, which can be merged into $k \pm 2$. But what about not-so-obvious ones, such as $2r\pi + \alpha$ and $(2r + 1)\pi - \alpha$. All the values of both these expressions can be seen to be included in $n\pi + (-1)^n\alpha$ (a trigonometric result from S.L. Loney's: Plane Trigonometry). I have'nt been properly introduced to such methods or results. If someone could elucidate this to me, that would be of much appreciation. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is quite vague.  In general, given a collection of algebraic expressions, it can be difficult to resolve them into a simpler collection (or to decide if such a simplification is possible). It depends very much on the collection itself.

Comment: @lulu is it true that for any collection of algebraic expressions, there does indeed exist one expression that includes within itself all the values of the previous expressions, though? And is there no mechanical procedure on finding this very expression?

Comment: Again, this is too vague.  It depends on the algebraic expressions.  It's not even clear what you mean by "algebraic expression".

Comment: @lulu Could you at least tell me which area of mathematics  I should research to reach a satisfying answer? I was guessing number theory, but I cannot rely on my own discretion.

Comment: I don't believe that your question is well defined enough to lead anywhere.  For the examples you described, the Chinese Remainder Theorem sometimes helps (but it won't resolve all such cases).  If you are interested in general issues of simplifying constraint sets...well, you run into things like the [Word Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics)#:~:text=In%20computational%20mathematics%2C%20a%20word,many%20other%20instances%20as%20well.) That is to say, even in simple (sounding) situations, the question of whether two expressions are the same might not be decidable.

Comment: @lulu could you explain to me where you find ambiguity in the question? I believe by "algebraic expression" I mean to say any expression that could be conjured using the symbols and functions of modern algebra (Implicitly I included transcendental symbols originating from trigonometry such as pi).

Comment: Well, The Word Problem certainly fits that description, and it is undecidable.

Comment: @lulu thank you much then, lulu. I shall look into it now.